# Lua if statement always goes to else option

Tags: lua

I am totally new to Lua and can't get my head around this: The following function always returns 99, even if the angleNumber is a 2,3,4 etc.

Am I overlooking some Lua syntax quirk?

```
local function mirroredNumber (angleNumber)
    
    if angleNumber == 2 then
        return 8
    elseif angleNumber == 3 then
        return 7
    elseif angleNumber == 4 then
        return 6
    elseif angleNumber == 6 then
        return 4
    elseif angleNumber == 7 then
        return 3
    elseif angleNumber == 8 then
        return 2
    else
        return 99
    end
end
```

I tried with setting a local variable in the if statement and return that in the end which also didn't work so I assume my if/elseif checks are wrong, but I cannot figure out how.

Comment: Are you sure that `angleNumber` is actually a number and not a string? What happens if you do `print(type(angleNumber))`? Is `angleNumber` *exactly* 2? What happens if you do `print(("%.17g"):format(angleNumber))`?

Comment: Right on the money.
It was not a number. I added ´´´angleNumber = tonumber(angleNumber)´´´ and it worked.
Thanks!

Comment: Alright, elaborated on the pitfalls in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two relevant Lua quirks, one of which I would suspect to be at play here:

- String - number coercion, but strict equality checking;
- Use of floats, but printing them inexactly, hiding rounding errors

Let's first simplify your example:

```lua
function f(x)
    if x == 1 then
        return 0
    end
    return 1
end
```

So `f(1)` is `0`, and `f(x)` is `1` for *every `x` that does not equal `1`*.

##### Strings that quack like numbers

Lua has a controversial "feature" where it coerces strings to numbers if you do arithmetic on them, and coerces numbers to strings if you do arithmetic on them; `print` just calls `tostring` internally, which doesn't quote strings, so strings very much "quack like numbers". However, testing for equality (or table indexing) is "strict"; it also requires the types to match. See this example:

```lua
-- Oops! This should be a number.
-- In practice this might be something less obvious like a function returning a string.
local x = "1"
print(x + 2) -- 3, we can do arithmetic as if it was a number!
print(x) -- 1, it looks just like it was a number!
print(type(x)) -- string
print("1" == 1) -- false, the types don't match
print(f(x)) -- 1, because "1" ~= 1
```

The solution here, assuming `x` is a string which comes from a file or similar, is to `tonumber(x)` (or equivalently: `x + 0`, which behaves roughly like `assert(tonumber(x))`).

##### Rounding errors

Lua uses floats to represent numbers. Floats can represent integers up to 2^53 accurately (without loss of precision), so very often this is not an issue when working with integers. However, you can construct floats that are very close to integers, but aren't integers under the hood. Unfortunately Lua *rounds* numbers when printing them, so you don't see this if you insert debug prints. Consider:

```lua
local x = 0.2 + 6 * 0.3
print(x) -- 2.0
print(x == 2) -- false, what? how does 2 not equal 2?
```

To uncover this, print `x` to 17 digits of precision:

```lua
print(("%.17g"):format(0.2 + 6 * 0.3)) -- 1.9999999999999998
```

If you know that you're working with inaccuracies, you should do comparisons with some "room for error". So instead of testing `x == 1`, you would test `math.abs(x - 1) < 1e-6`, where `1e-6` would be your (absolute) margin for error in this example. (Note: A relative margin for error may be more appropriate sometimes; floats in particular guarantee certain relative errors).

---

Side note: In many languages with `switch`es, pattern matching or similar, a function and a `switch` + `return` may be an idiomatic way to implement this. However, given that this is just a mapping from some numbers to other numbers, you would usually use a table in Lua:

```lua
local mirrored_numbers = {
    [2] = 8,
    [3] = 7,
    -- ... and so on
}
local function mirror_number(x)
    return mirrored_numbers[x] or 99
end
```

(also, there seems to be a simple correspondence between "mirrored" numbers and `x` (`if angleNumber >= 2 and angleNumber <= 8 then return 10 - angleNumber end`), unless you just simplified it for this example; why not leverage that?)

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed explanation of what is going on. I had none of this on my radar.
Also thanks for the alternatives to my function^^ I*ll probably implement them once everything else works.